# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: "_main", referenced from: implicit entry/start for main executable

Tags: c

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
dhanushn@ELON DS PROGRAM %
```

can anybody pls help me to solve this problem?
my program was running well but suddenly now its not compiling

Comment: The linker did not find a definition of the `main` function. Do you *have* a `main` function (and it somehow did not end up in the binary), or did you forget to define one? Also, [Q: What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816).

Comment: Completely legitimate problem specific to mac os X (arm64 and clang are the hints).  Answer referenced for the duplicate is not an answer to the problem proposed by the OP.

Answer (score -1):

It may be that the content in the editor has not been saved

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Also a pretty long shot, given what little information is in the question...